# App Engine custom domain with service

Tags: google-app-engine, custom-domain

I [set up a custom domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY1Ki.png) with App Engine after following the instructions on DNS records:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mapping-custom-domains

It's working for the default service using URL
http://MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN but I'm unable to access other services with URLs http://SERVICE_ID.MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN. Do I need to map a different set of DNS records?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check how to use subdomains and how wildcard mapping works in the GCP docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#using_subdomains) (actually these are the next steps at the website which you've followed and linked). Make sure that your DNS provider permits wildcards in `CNAME` host entries, otherwise such mapping will not be possible.

[This blog post](https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2017/10/15/google-app-engine-using-subdomains/) shows a real-life example of matching subdomains to services with App Engine.

Comment: Key take away, if your service is named "api" and you create a custom domain for "api.expample.com", App Engine will automatically match it.

Comment: @howMuchCheeseIsTooMuchCheese In my case I found only http works, if you need TLS connection, dispatch.yaml seems the only way.

Answer (score 28):

Here's a step-by-step:

1. Ensure you are a owner of the parent domain in here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home (e.g for `subdomain.example.com` you need to own `example.com`)
   If not, ask a friend to add you as an owner.
2. Create a *CNAME* record pointing to: `ghs.googlehosted.com` (in Cloud DNS or wherever).
   **Note**: This will cause downtime, but it is required for App Engine to create an SSL certificate so downtime is unavoidable...
3. Add custom domain to App Engine

   1. Go to `App Engine -> Settings -> Custom Domains`
   2. Click on `Add a custom domain`
   3. Choose the verified parent domain and click `Continue`
   4. Enter the subdomain (e.g `subdomain.example.com`) and click `Save mappings`
   5. Click `Done` (you already did this last step)
4. Update App Engine dispatch rules

   1. Run `gcloud app describe --project <GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID>` and take a look at the current section of `dispatchRules`
   2. Create `dispatch.yaml` or `dispatch.yml` file with your new rule as well as the ones already existing above (note the file format is different from the command output)

   ```
   dispatch:
     - url: <DOMAIN>/* # e.g. subdomain.example.com/*
       service: <SERVICE-NAME>
   ```

   3. Deploy it using: `gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml --project <GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID>`

Comment: @henry-woody both `dispatch.yaml` and `dispatch.yml` work

Comment: Is it possible to do sub-domain only? Which is a very common use case?

Comment: I am looking for an approach not using dispatch.yaml, per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#urls