# Problem Mapping a subdomain to an GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, url, google-cloud-platform, subdomain

I have a GAE app (Aggregate web site) at the url projectname.appspot.com

Now, I bought a domain mydomain.com from LWS and I want to map the subdomain projectname.mydomain.com to projectname.appspot.com

After setting all the required steps suggested by GAE, I'm able to reach my GAE app via projectname.mydomain.com; but, once the page finishes loading, instead of the new url (my hope), the old one (projectname.appspot.com) still displaying in the address bar of my browser.

Comment: Did you follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains) documentation? All the necessary steps about custom domains are described here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes, I followed successfully all these steps.

Comment: Have you seen [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56619600/8963486) ?

Comment: Not yet.
I will see it now and try to apply it.
Thanks so much.
Regards,

Comment: Please, where (in which console) should I type the codes at the point 4. of the above link?
gcloud app describe --project <GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID>
etc
Thanks

Comment: It can be done either in Cloud Shell on your GCP project page, either in your terminal if you installed the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install)