# How to configure custom domain for App Engine for service that is not the defautl in GCP?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, custom-domain

I have one Node aplication runing on default App Engine service. Its was runing on "urlFromWebSite.appspot.com", and I config it to run in my domain url "customUrl.ai".

I built a second service with Node with name "second-service",and its runing at
"service-two-doturlFromWebSite.appspot.com", but i want to run at "subDomain.customUrl.ai"

I tried dispatch.yaml file with the url that i want for 'second-service';

[Stack post 1 talking about dipatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480940/app-engine-custom-domain-with-service)

[Stack post 1 talking about dipatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480940/app-engine-custom-domain-with-service)

[GCP explanation for dispatch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml)

I have tried Custom domains in App Engine > Settings > Custom domains;

[GCP documentation for mapping custom domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains?csw=1)

At custom domains I config my subdomain url, and it generates the DNS. ´

[image]

I have question here:
Where should I add this DNS config? At the "customUrl" or should i create a new record set for it?

I have been strugling with it for 2 days already, and could figure it out how to solve it. How should i config this to change my second service's url for a custom subdomain?

Comment: Those records are created at the authoritative name server for your domain.

Comment: Hi @Modena, did you try to update CNAME, A or AAA A records in your domain service provider's DNS settings in case you already have an existing DNS record?

Comment: @CatherineO I am not sure. I am not sure where i should do this. My domain is from GoDaddy. Should i do this at GoDaddy or at the Network Services > Clooud DNS?

Comment: @JohnHanley what are they used for? Should I do something with at the GCP?

Comment: Please reread my first comment. Create those records at the DNS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When user enters `customUrl.ai` in a browser, traffic should be routed to Google's servers (for your GAE project). To do that, you configure DNS settings on your **domain registrar's end**.
2. When user enters `subDomain.customUrl.ai` in a browser, traffic should be routed to Google's servers. To do that, you also configure DNS settings on your **domain registrar's end**.
3. Both #1 & #2 are done for the same domain on your **domain registrar's** end (which is GoDaddy in your case). I believe this is what @JohnHanley is referring to. Put another way - just go to GoDaddy, find your domain and create entries corresponding to what GAE has outlined for you. If they are duplicates, GoDaddy will tell you.